# Facebook app iframe certificate issue on Safari for Mac

Tags: iis, iis-7, https, safari, ssl-certificate

I am running into a certificate issue when using facebook iframe app on Safari for MAC - "The website requires a client certificate" (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyXWo.jpg)
The protocol being used for the entire website is HTTPS and we host our website using IIS 7 on a Windows server.

We run across this issue only on our facebook iframe app.
We have a valid GoDaddy issued certificate and it works fine on all browsers except Safari.

Any ideas as to what the problem could be here? 
I tried Googling this issue, but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to your problem? If yes, please post it as an answer so that the community can benefit from the same. Thanks.